# Error al subir al servidor proyecto de Symfony

Tags: php, servidor, symfony, symfony4

Tengo un proyecto de Symfony y al intentar subirlo al servidor, me da el siguiente error:

```
Attempted to load class "AbstractExpression" from namespace "Twig\Node\Expression".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

En el servidor local va todo perfectamente.

¿Alguien sabría cómo arreglarlo?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: suena a que no se han generado los vendors. has instalado composer y los has creado?

Comment: Si sí, osea el proyecto en el servidor local me va perfecto, pero lo subo al servidor externo y me salta este error